# CMake cannot locate io.h

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

I'm trying to install OpenCV 2.4.9 on Ubuntu 18.04. I'm using this command:

`cmake -D BUILD_TIFF=ON -D WITH_CUDA=OFF -D ENABLE_AVX=OFF -D WITH_OPENGL=OFF -D WITH_OPENCL=OFF -D WITH_IPP=OFF -D WITH_TBB=ON -D BUILD_TBB=ON -D WITH_EIGEN=OFF -D WITH_V4L=OFF -D WITH_VTK=OFF -D BUILD_TESTS=OFF -D BUILD_PERF_TESTS=OFF -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local /opt/opencv-2.4.9/`

But it says `Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!`

When I checked `CMakeError.log` get these two error messages:

1) `/opt/opencv-2.4.9/release/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckIncludeFile.c:1:10: fatal error: io.h: No such file or directory`

2) `/opt/opencv-2.4.9/release/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckIncludeFile.c:1:10: fatal error: ffmpeg/avformat.h: No such file or directory`

I'm able to locate numerous `io.h` files in my OS and `avformat.h` is also there. I guess I'm missing some path setting. Please suggest.

Comment: Message `Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!` is **not an error description**. It is like a summary message. Actual error message(s) is(are) **above** that line (and **not** in `CMakeError.log` or other files).

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks for the suggestion. In OpenCVDetectCXXCompiler.cmake, we need to change "dumpversion" to "dumpfullversion".